# Build error when trying to build project with proto

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, proto

Trying to add `proto` datastore to my application, but it keeps giving me this error when I build

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDeployDebugProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: Missing output directives.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This is my `.proto` file

```
syntax = "proto3";
    
option java_package = "net.inferno.quakereport.model";
option java_multiple_files = true;
    
message UserPreferences {
  optional string order_by = 1;
  optional double min_mag = 2;
  optional double latitude = 3;
  optional double longitude = 4;
}
```

And these are my `build.gradle` declarations

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.18"
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.4")
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.4"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                getByName("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm following the codelabs [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add

> multiDexEnabled true

to your defaultConfig?

You should also look for duplicated jar files that might occur after some updates. Delete the old ones...

Comment: I tried `multiDex`. And not sure what you mean about duplicated jars? I'm using `rebuild` or `clean` so there shouldn't be any build files

Comment: Getting this error, not sure if it's related `Path [J:/Programming/Android_Projects/QuakeReport/app/build/generated/source/kapt/deployDebug] of module [Quake_Report.app.main] was removed from modules [Quake_Report.app.main]" Also 2 more paths were deduplicated. See idea log for details`

Comment: Please post these logs. Let's take a look